# Will Junit execute the @Test case when the code in the @before Section fails?

Tags: junit4

I'm new to Junit.
If I execute something in the @before part, and my code fails. e.g. I want to make a server connection, but it fails for some reason.

Will Junit execute my Test in the @Test section even if the @before fails? Because then my test would fail because I haven't a server connection. How can I handle it if its the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out with a basic junit.

```java
public class SamplePlayTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("Before called");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test case called");
    }

}
```

This gives output as

> Before called

And fails with error `java.lang.RuntimeException`. `Test case called` is not printed.